# simulate dice with fair coin flip

Tags: simulation, probability

Given a fair coin (0/1), how do you simulate fair dice(0 to 5)
Obvious answer I know is toss 3 times, treat each toss as a bit to produce (2^3 = 0 to 7)
If result == 7, discard and repeat.

Well, theoretically worst case big-O of this is really bad (another question in itself, something to do with monte-carlo algos). Lets keep this soln on shelf.

So now my question is, 
 Is there/can there be n number of coin toss that can guarantee simulation of dice ?
Of course if exists would like to know minimum number of tosses. :)

In absence of a number that is both divisible by three and 2^n, I couldnt think of any way to solve this. :(

Comment: sounds like an assignment question... what programming language do you want to use?

Comment: Don't you mean divisible by 6 and 2^n? Do you know for a fact a better solution than this exists?

Comment: Shouldn't result == 7 be result >= 6 ?

Comment: Great, can't post my answer. Comment instead: This is impossible. For *n* tosses, there are *m* = 2^n possible results. Getting a fair roll requires that there are an even number of results we could assign to each face of the die -- i.e., of the *m* results m/6 of those should represent each face of the die.  But 2^n is not evenly divisible by 6, thus there cannot be a fair solution for fixed *n*.

Comment: OMG ! How is NOT A ALGORITHM QUESTION ?  Did I have to put "Write a program in C++ " to output 0to6 with equal probability given a function that could return 0 or 1 ???

Comment: @freiheit :Yes. My mistake. I should have said    0<= n <=5

Comment: @shivan : I would be really surprised if they start giving this complex questions in assignment. Please read question more carefully and you will know I am not asking the obv answer..
Btw, I would prefer C++ :)

Comment: I don't really see how "theoretically the Big O of this is really bad". That's still O(1) - on average you'll need 1.25*3 coin tosses.

Comment: @Voo, I never mentioned 'average' I said 'worst' case. You know ppl in embedded/RT systems would dislike anything that doesnt give them time guarantee even for worst case right ?